# Creating custom link types to open the app

Tags: android

So the objective is to create some unique type that will open with my app only. This should happen throughout the OS. Ex: suppose my app opens when you click a number like #12345678.90. Where ever this type of number appears, it should automatically become a link and open my app on clicking it.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure if you use deep linking

You need to add the following lines to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="gizmos" />
```

But this only works if you have an uri with whatever scheme you may wish.

Can it be different than #12345678.90? or is this the requirement?

[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

Comment: This does not force all strings of the OP's desired pattern to be clickable, let alone reach the OP's app, let alone *uniquely* reach the OP's app

Comment: Well number or link it's the same, as he wants something to click on. not to type.

Comment: Yes it can be different than #12345678.90 also. Ex: myApp://#1234567890 can be used as a custom uri and make my app read such uri is enough right?

Comment: No, it is not, insofar as other apps will not magically make such strings clickable. You can *respond* to such a `Uri`, but other apps will not know to actually link to such strings, outside of HTML that you craft yourself (and even then I don't know whether all browsers will necessarily honor `<a>` elements to unrecognized schemes).

Comment: Well there's nothing else you can do for that at least I don't know any way to change that.

Answer (score 2):

> So the objective is to create some unique type that will open with my app only

By definition, that is impossible for an SDK app. If you can write the code to support responding to some action, so can anybody else, and the user is welcome to install 2+ apps that contain such code.

> This should happen throughout the OS

That too is impossible, unless you build your own ROM mod that somehow forces all occurrences of some string to magically become clickable and magically route to your app.

The closest thing to what you are seeking is if your app has an `<intent-filter>` with a `<data>` attribute that matches a pattern supported by `Linkify`, akin to Benoit's answer. Many apps use `Linkify`, directly or indirectly (e.g., via `android:autoLink` on a `TextView`), to make substrings clickable without any programming. However:

- `Linkify` does not support arbitrary patterns
- Not every app uses `Linkify`, and if your string shows up in those places, it is not necessarily going to be clickable
- Any app can support the *same* pattern as you (e.g., Benoit's example will be supported by browsers, as well as your app)

Comment: Thank you. So I can define my own uri which will open my app since linkify supports uri's.

Comment: @VyprNoch: Yes, if you have an `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_VIEW` and a `<data>` element akin to Benoit's. But it will have to be a recognized scheme, as `Linkify` does not assume everything with a colon in it is a `Uri`. It specifically will need to use an `http`, `https`, or `rtsp` scheme, per [the current `Linkify` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java), as I read it. That means that other apps will also respond to those links, not just yours.